# My datePicker is not working when i click after i empelment select with vue | Laravel - js

Tags: laravel, datepicker, laravel-blade, ui-select2, laravel-vue

im new at Laravel And i have this problem when i use vue for select another data My date picker stopped working and when i click on it is not shown ,

this is the HTML code :

```
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                        @include('new_admin.components.inputs.datepicker', [
                            'options' => [
                                'name'   => 'created_at_from',
                                'label'  => trans('admin_index.created_at') . ' (' . trans('admin_index.from') . ')',
                                'value'  => old('created_at_from'),
                            ]
                        ])
                    </div>
```

and when i use this script :

```
 var SearchApplication = new Vue({
        el: '#datatable1-advanced-search',
        data: {
            sku: null,
        },
    });
```

the datepicker stopped showing .

Answer (score 0):

for any one faced the same problem i just make a new datepicker in the same HTML page
without include it from another page and make a new script for the date picker also in  same page and now it's working fine